# Auto return type matching void

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is this code legal? It compiles but I'm wondering what happens with the return value. Undefined behavior?

```
class Foo {
public:
    void test1() {

    }
    auto test() -> decltype(test1()) {
        return test1(); //<---return void here!
    }
};
```

Comment: A void function can return another void function. A void function can even return  (void)"I'm a void";

Comment: There are rules in place in the C++ spec that allow a void function to return a void value, to handle cases where templated functions may need to do exactly that without having to use special treatment just for void

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed this question came from a doubt using a template function :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is legal. `auto` deduces to `void` and a `void` function can return another `void` function. A `void` function can even

```
return static_cast<void>("I'm a void");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's legal, but you can't, for example, assign the result to a variable. [1]

```
class Foo {
public:
    void test1() {

    }
    auto test() -> decltype(test1()) {
        return test1(); //<---return void here!
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    auto x = foo.test(); //<---compile error here
}
```

[1] https://godbolt.org/z/YGAtdJ

Comment: I guess this should be obvious, as you cannot have a `void x = whatever();` anyway [?]